# is there a way to bind variables to an html file in the public/ directory in rails

Tags: templates, jquery-templates, ruby-on-rails-2

i have the following file:

```
#{RAILS_ROOT}/public/mytemplate/index.html
```

which in an html file with certain template-like variables like so:

```
<div class="hover">
  <h1 id="user_name">{user_name}</h1>
</div>

<h2 id="project_name">{project_name}</h2>
```

From a controller action, i need to render this file, which i am doing with

```
render :file => "#{RAILS_ROOT}/public/mytemplate/index.html"
```

but i want to map variables to the template values. for example, i want to specify that @project.name maps to project_name. How can i specify this mapping?

Answer (score 0):

In the controller action, add the following code:
`project_name = @project.name`
I think this is what you want, right?